# Can I trademark a 10-year-old-dead-trademark?

Tags: united-states, trademark

According to US law, if trademark 'ABC' has expired under 'Section 8/9' more than 10 years ago (2010), and has not seen any activity so far, can I trademark it?

Comment: Try https://www.uspto.gov/trademarks-application-process/search-trademark-database

Comment: @BlueDogRanch The link you provided does not offer any information regarding Cancelled/Expired trademarks.

Comment: Of course it does; you can search for dead trademarks.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Yes, but that's not my question.

Comment: "Who should i contact" is asking for legal or business advice; neither is answered here.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch If so, the entirety of the question apart this specific line is still valid. I'll edit the offending part.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch "*"Who should i contact" is asking for legal or business advice*" Procedure is fully on-topic here, including what official to contact in specific circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research, you can **IF**:

1. The trademark is **NOT** used in trade, per example, if Apple failed to renew the trademark but is activelly using on products, they can always renew filling a new application.

   [As said on Trademark Now](https://www.trademarknow.com/blog/4-considerations-before-purchasing-a-dead-trademark):

   > The risk comes from the Lanham Act.
   >
   > Through this act, a mark is not abandoned until it’s been discontinued
   >   without intent to resume use. While the USPTO will not track the mark
   >   in their registry as active because the paperwork has not been filed,
   >   this doesn’t mean that the mark isn’t still being used by a business
   >   who has an acceptable reason for not maintaining it in the registry.
   >
   > If you can prove in court that the original owner had no intent to
   >   continue its use, then have at it. Understand, however, that the
   >   subjectivity of the process will give you problems if the previous
   >   owner pushes back.

2. The expired trademark is **NOT** in the 6-month grace period after expiration in wich, the original owner can renew.

I learned also that you could always ask(And is the best course of action), i spoke with some companies who had expired trademarks and they usually are willing grant the trademark, since the product/brand has been long dead.